# on click for dynamically assigned variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick

I'm fairly new to js and jquery and have been struggling with some code for quite awhile now.  I see some similar questions posted but when I try to implement the solutions I still do not get the behavior I want.
The tweets are loaded, some have urls in them others do not.  If a user clicks on a url in a tweet I want it to open in a new window.  I'm pretty sure something is going on with the onclick function (maybe not being assigned to the variable correctly?) because if I remove the onclick a new window is opened for every url that is brought in.
First, I create the link variable and pull out the rest of the text so I can append the url as a hyperlink.  If the user clicks on the url I want to open the variable link1 (which I've pulled from directly from the api) in a new window.

```
           var link="";
           if(tweet.entities.urls[0]!=null){
            if(tweet.entities.urls[0].url!=null){
                var link1=tweet.entities.urls[0].url;
                link=replaceLinks(link1);
                $('link').live('click', function(){
                    window.open(link1);
                });
        }
        }
           if(tweet.geo==null){
                $("#geo").append('<p><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" widt="48" height="48" />'+tweet.text+link+'</p>');
          }
```

The `$('link').live('click', function(){` line is the last method I tried, though I've tried numerous other onclick assignments.  I've been testing this in firefox and using aptana in case that matters.  I would include more code but after lots of testing I really think the problem(s) are in the lines I've included, though I will gladly include more if this isn't enough to determine the problem.  This is my first web app so if I'm doing something very obviously wrong kindly let me know what it is?!  Thanks so much!

Comment: What is `$('link')` supposed to select? Currently it will select all the `<link />` elements on the page. You want to bind to the actual DOM element that has the link... Also, what does the `replaceLinks()` function do?

Comment: live() is deprecated, use on() if using jQuery 1.7+. Also, you're passing the string 'link' as an element, it's not a class nor an ID, and would'nt match anything other than perhaps tagnames, and link is'nt a valid tagname, if trying to use the variable, remove the quotes on 'link'.

Comment: link isn't a class or id and I thought that may be the problem.  The reason is that some tweets don't have hyperlinks so I would only use an element if it could be dynamically assigned and created and just as easily removed - seemed much easier to just use a string if it can be done, though maybe it can't.   ReplaceLinks() just takes the line of text and turns the url portion into a hyperlink.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused about what is the id of your link. You have quotes around your link variable, if it is supposed to contain the link id then it should be like this:

```
$(link).live('click', function(){
    window.open(link1);
});
```

If link is the actual id or a class of your link then it should be like this:

```
$('#link').live('click', function(){ // id
$('.link').live('click', function(){ // class
```

**Edit**:

Also to note, depending on the version of jQuery you are using, [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated and should be replace by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    window.open(link1);
});
```